# Two Sum Test at Testdome for Python - How to Pass the Performance Test?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I am writing a function that, given a list of `numbers` and a `target_sum`, returns zero-based indices of **any** two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should return (-1, -1).

That's the solution I came up with:

```
class TwoSum:

    @staticmethod
    def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
        """
        :param numbers: (list of ints) The list of numbers.
        :param target_sum: (int) The required target sum.
        :returns: (a tuple of 2 ints) The indices of the two elements whose sum is equal to target_sum
        """
        numbers = list(sorted(numbers))  # added after the update
        # to make sure numbers are always sorted        
        lo_index = 0
        hi_index = len(numbers) - 1
        while lo_index < hi_index:
            pair_sum = numbers[lo_index] + numbers[hi_index]
            if pair_sum < target_sum:
                lo_index += 1
            elif pair_sum > target_sum:
                hi_index -= 1
            else:
                return (lo_index, hi_index)
        return (-1, -1)


print(TwoSum.find_two_sum([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 12))  # I assume the list is already sorted
```

I found this challenge at [testdome](https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/two-sum/14289?visibility=1&skillId=9) and I am wondering why this code fails for the last test with the message `Performance test with a large number of elements: Wrong answer`. I am currently practicing for recruitment tests and thought that this solution would be good enough.

**Update:**

I guess the solution I came up with is totally fine. I just want to add the execution times on my machine for the answers given so far. I added to my function `numbers = list(sorted(numbers))` as mentioned in the comments.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_jdehesa([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 12))
3.0298462831085544
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_delirious_lettuce([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 12))
1.6323729552793793
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_op([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 12))
1.23889097157587
```

**Update 2:**

```
import random

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_jdehesa(random.sample(range(1, 1000), 500), random.randint(1, 999)), number=10000)
8.197637722340914
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_delirious_lettuce(random.sample(range(1, 1000), 500), random.randint(1, 999)), number=10000)
5.175919267269819
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: find_two_op(random.sample(range(1, 1000), 500), random.randint(1, 999)), number=10000)
6.3352265931093825
```

Comment: Aside: If you've got a class that's only there to have a static method - you don't need a class...

Comment: In all fairness to the OP, the testdome example given uses this class+static function as part of its automatic test/run framework, not his fault

Comment: The exercise doesn't really say the input list will be sorted.

Comment: Is your input `numbers` always sorted? If not it seems like this would not work. What if your answer was `(1, 98)` for a list of 100 elements but both `(0, 99)` and `(1, 99)` were `< target_sum`? Your `lo_index` would be `2` and `(1, 98)` would never be checked.

Comment: @scnerd sure - if that's the only way to get it to run through the framework then fine... just advising that it shouldn't be seen as a design practice in real use...

Comment: Just by adding `numbers = list(sorted(numbers))` to the top of your function, one of the tests fails that succeeded before... so clearly, you can't assume that this is the case going in. Regardless, the parameter merely says "a list of numbers", so you ought to be able to take any list, not just a sorted one (otherwise it would say so)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my solution from the two sum question on LeetCode (modified to fit into your class) but it should work the same here:

```
class TwoSum:
    @staticmethod
    def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
        seen = {}
        for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
            try:
                return (seen[num], i)
            except KeyError:
                seen[target_sum - num] = i
        return (-1, -1)
```

Comment: @YannicHamann This question seems like one of those classic tradeoffs between time and space complexity. This answer would have a better time complexity because it doesn't have to sort the numbers before iterating over them. The tradeoff is a much higher space complexity. Your solution may have a greater time complexity but it uses much less space. Since the question didn't explicitly say the numbers were always sorted, I think this is the right way to go. If you were sure the numbers were guaranteed to be sorted, I would go with your original algorithm (without the sorting).

Comment: Brilliant!  
Now I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is essentially fine, but you are not taking into account that the input may not be sorted, so you have to sort it first and keep track of the sorted indices, so you can return the right index values later:

```
class TwoSum:

    @staticmethod
    def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
        """
        :param numbers: (list of ints) The list of numbers.
        :param target_sum: (int) The required target sum.
        :returns: (a tuple of 2 ints) The indices of the two elements whose sum is equal to target_sum
        """
        # Sort numbers and get sorted indices
        numbers, idx = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(numbers, range(len(numbers))))))
        if len(numbers) < 2:
            return (-1, -1)
        i = 0
        j = len(numbers) - 1
        while i < j:
            s = numbers[i] + numbers[j]
            if s == target_sum:
                # Return indices from the unsorted list
                return (idx[i], idx[j])
            elif s < target_sum:
                i += 1
            elif s > target_sum:
                j -= 1
        return (-1, -1)

print(TwoSum.find_two_sum([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 12))
```

Comment: You don't need to sort it at all and in an interview question that seems like bad advice since you are unnecessarily increasing the algorithms complexity.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Umh, well I guess that depends on the interview, but what I can tell is that you _need_ to solve it for the testdome exercise referred by the OP, otherwise it will not pass the tests.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Obviously, I meant that you need to sort it to solve it in the way the OP was solving it. You algorithm is fine too I assume (at least in a batteries-included language like Python, not so easy if you are asked to do it in C).

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Okay dude look I already explained I said that in the context of the posted code, but whatever you say. I posted an answer fixing the code posted by the OP so the testdome exercise passes, and explaining what was the problem in the posted code. It is a valid answer as it is, same as yours, I didn't say it's perfect, or the best possible or the only one. You already said you think it's not good, feel free to downvote or whatever you want, but keeping posting pointless comments is not really useful for any of us.

Comment: Thanks to both of you... I updated my test cases and hope I hope you find these interesting as well as I do.

Answer (score 0):

I test at test dome. it meets all requirement except for large data

```
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
"""
:param numbers: (list of ints) The list of numbers.
:param target_sum: (int) The required target sum.
:returns: (a tuple of 2 ints) The indices of the two elements whose sum is equal to target_sum
"""
i = 0
j = len(numbers) - 1
while i < j:
    if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target_sum:
        return (i, j)
    if numbers[i] + numbers[j] < target_sum:
        i += 1

    else:
        j -= 1

return None
```

print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10))

Comment: improve answer using enumerate

Answer (score 0):

based on the hints provided by testDome:

Hint 1: Nested for loops can iterate over the list and calculate a sum in O(N^2) time.

Hint 2: A dict can be used to store pre-calculated values, this may allow a solution with O(N) complexity.

I have the following solution:

```
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
    taken = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
        diff = target_sum - num
        if diff in taken:
            return i, taken[diff]
        taken[num] = i

my_list = [3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9]
print(find_two_sum(my_list, 10))
```

I get the following result:

```
Run OK
(3, 0) 
Your score is 100%, perfect!
```